# How does one change to TV audio output automatically after connecting to HDMI?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, system-settings

I am using Ubuntu 22.04, and every time I connect to my TV through HDMI, I have to manually select the TV to be my sound output. Is there any way for me to automate that?

Headphone pairing automatically does this (for obvious reasons), so it sounds doable, it's just a matter of asking the right person. I tried asking ChatGPT 4 for help, but to no end.

Comment: Never heard of a TV sound output. Are you sure it is not HDMI that you can select? From your question I tried asking ChatGPT 4 for help Who is this?

Comment: @David that was I type out. Is the question clearer now?